# How to evaluate $\frac13 + \frac29 + \frac3{27}\dots\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $$P = 3^{\frac13}\times3^{\frac29}\times3^{\frac3{27}}\dots\infty$$

What would be the value of $P^{1/3}?$

$$P = 3^{1/3\ +\ 2/9 +\ 3/27\dots\infty}$$ $$Let\ S = \frac13 + \frac29 + \frac3{27}\dots\infty$$

How would I evaluate $S?$ I see 2 series in it, the one in the numerator, i.e, $1+2+3+4\dots$ and the one in the denominator $3+9+27\dots$ but can't proceed further.

Comment: Hint: Differentiate 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Is there a way to evaluate the series without differentiation or integration?

Comment: Hint: calculate $S-\frac13 S$

Comment: This is an [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence).

Comment: @peterwhy That link helped me, I didn't notice mine was a duplicate question. Thanks!

Comment: You don't want to multiply by ∞ or add ∞ or raise a number to the ∞ power. (Three dots suffice to indicate what you mean.)

Comment: @DanAsimov Noted.